# Aseh Lmaan Yeminecha - עשה למען ימינך

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

At the end of Shemona Esrei we say the following in Nusach Sefard:

> עשה למען שמך, עשה למען ימינך, עשה למען תורתך, עשה למען קדושתך.

In Nusach Ashkenaz we say Kedushasecha before Torasecha.

Translation is Do for the sake of your (God's) name, Do for the sake of your right hand, Do for the sake of the Torah, Do for the sake of your holiness.

I am trying to understand what the deeper meaning of "עשה למען ימינך" "Do for the sake of your right hand" is.

To Do for the sake of your (God's) name, Do for the sake of the Torah, Do for the sake of your holiness, seems all clear cut, however Do for the sake of your right hand needs an explanation?

Has anyone seen an explanation of these words?

Comment: See here (without source): https://www.hidabroot.org/question/34047

Answer (score 1):

I excerpted the last translation in this [beureihatefilla](https://beureihatefila.com/files/2007-08-24_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf) article:

> At the time of the destruction of the Temple, Your name was
>   desecrated, as it is written: My holy name that you desecrated. **The
>   power of G-d’s right hand was weakened as it is written: He put His
>   right hand behind Him because of the enemy**. The power of Torah was
>   lost as it is written: the King and his officers among the nations
>   have no Torah. And G-d’s holiness was desecrated as it is written: and
>   they occupied Your Temple. That is why we make these four requests:
>   Asei L’Ma’An Sh’mecha; Asei L’Ma’An Yiminecha; Asei L’Ma’An Torosecha;
>   Asei L’Ma’An Keduchasecha.

I'd appreciate if someone can edit in where this verse is from. The Hebrew phrasing is a few pages above the English citing.